# Counterexample for convergence or $X_n$ and $Y_n$ in $L^2$ implies convergence of $X_nY_n$ in $L^2$ (quadratic mean)

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I know that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ in $L^2$ implies convergence of $X_nY_n$ in $L^1$ using a combination of Minkowski's and Cauchy-Schwartz, which leads me to believe that this is not always true. However, I can't think of any counter examples.

Comment: Why does $X_nY_n$ belong to $L^{2}$?  (Think of the case $X_n=Y_n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that $X_n Y_n$ may not even be in $L^2$.
For example, we could take $X_n = Y_n$ with density
$$
f(x)
= 3x^{-4} \mathbf{1}_{x > 1},
$$
so that $X_n, Y_n$ are the same for each $n$ and in $L^2$, so they each converge in $L^2$, but you can check that $\mathbf{E} (X_n Y_n)^2 = \mathbf{E} X_n^4 = \infty$ so that $X_n Y_n$ is not in $L^2$.